# For loop inside vs outside function

Tags: julia

I've been experimenting with this for a while but can't seem to come to a conclusion. If I have the following options,

```
function fxn1()
    for i in 1:N
        do_something()
    end
end

function main()
    fxn1()
end
```

and

```
function fxn2()
    do_something()
end

function main()
    for i in 1:N
        fxn2()
    end
end
```

Is there a general consensus on which one is preferred? I have been playing around with @time, and have been getting mixed results.

What surprised me were the instances when the second option was faster, since I would expect the extra subroutine/function calls to make the code a bit more expensive. I paid attention to memory allocations, which were nearly the same for both cases for each of the experiments I did, and even then the lesser wasn't necessarily the faster.

Thanks in advance for any input!

Comment: I can't answer the immediate question, but if performance is your concern you could investigate loop unrolling. This COULD have a big impact if used in the inner loop. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unrolling

Comment: I think that can be handled by Julia's compiler.

Answer (score 3):

So, it's hard to answer given the MWE. I mean why would you even have function fxn2()?
But to say something general, in Julia you generally prefer defining a function on a single element, then iterate across that element to apply it. This plays nicely with the broadcasting semantics of julia (see eg https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/functions/#man-vectorized-1)

So as an example, if you want to take the `sin`e  of an array of numbers in Julia, you would do `y = sin.(x)` which is the same as

```
y = Vector{Float64}(undef, length(x))
for i in eachindex(x)
   y[i] = sin(x[i])
end
```

Comment: I agree in general. Write a simple function, then iterate over that. A simple function will likely be inlined anyway, so no function call overhead. But your loop example here returns `nothing`, so that doesn't work.

Comment: :-O it does! OK let me change it